# Unhandled Exception: PlatformException (channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase

I don't get this error in IOS simulator, but I have this problem in android studio emulator.

> I/tart.coner0_0_0( 4244): Compiler allocated 4579KB to compile void android. view. ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()
> E/flutter (4244): [ERROR: flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception:
> PlatformException (channel-error, Unable to establish connection on
> channel., null, null)
> E/flutter ( 4244): #0
> FirebaseCoreHostApi.initializeCore(package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:203:7)
> E/flutter (4244): 
> E/flutter ( 4244): #1
> MethodChannelFirebase._initializeCore(package:firebase.core_platform_interface/src/method
> channel/method channel firebase
> dart: 29:44)
> E/flutter (4244): 
> E/flutter (4244): #2
> MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApppackagerfinebasecone_platform_interface/src/methodchannel/methodchannelfirebase
> dart: 73:7)
> E/flutter (4244): 
> E/flutter (4244): #3
> Firebase. initializeApp (package:firebase core/src/firebase. dart:43:31)
> E/flutter (4244): 
> E/flutter (4244): #4 main (package:coner0 0 0/main.dart:22:3)
> E/flutter (4244): ‹asynchronous suspension>
> E/flutter (4244):

[image]

I tried pub upgrade, and I also tried updating flutter, but the symptoms are the same.

I tried to update firebase and flutter.

```
 pubspec.yaml
      
 admob_flutter: ^3.0.0
 firebase_auth: ^4.3.0
 cloud_firestore: ^4.4.5
 firebase_core: ^2.8.0
 firebase_storage: ^11.0.16     
 firebase_core_platform_interface: ^4.5.3
```

Project/build.gradle

```
        buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-              plugin:$kotlin_version"
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        }
        allprojects {
          repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
          }
        }
```

main.dart

```
Future<void> main() async {      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
      await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .setSettings(appVerificationDisabledForTesting: true);
      Admob.initialize();
      runApp(const MyApp());
    }
```

Comment: We would need to see the code you have written to try to understand the problem

Comment: What code content do you need??

Comment: maybe a VPN issue? you could verify other types of network connection work. (do you have the internet permission)

Comment: I added   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
Are there any additional actions I need to take?

Comment: Not that I can think of in the context sorry